# Why is audio coming out of only one ear in my headphones in this multicam sequence?

Tags: premiere

I've set the original audio to mono, and the multicam sequence is also mono. The original clip comes through both ears in the headphones, but in the multicam sequence it doesn't. This video will make things more clear:

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does this by default.
As you are only using one channel of audio, it only plays from one of your two speakers.

If you want to hear it from two speakers, your sequence is going to need to have two channels, and then your mono audio track needs to be set centrally between those two channels.

The way I usually resolve this is to drag my multicam sequence into a "normal" sequence, then adjust the pan controls on that clip. For some reason, the pan controls are often set to be keyframe enabled (animated), so turn that off before you start editing, otherwise you'll have to disable it individually in every clip you cut.

Also, multicam editing is still buggy.  If you have any weirdness and don't need the audio to reflect your camera cuts, I often just make sure my "normal" sequence has identical settings to my multicam sequence (apart from the number of channels), then just bring the audio into the normal sequence as a normal clip.

Any other multicam weirdness is usally resolved by restarting Premiere.